# How to expose public properties with jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, plugins, methods, properties, public

I'm building a small plugin, using jQuery, but I want it to expose some of its data as public properties. For example:

```
$(function () {
        $("#example1").myPlugin({
            exampleData: 'bar'
        });
        $("#example2").myPlugin({
            exampleData: 'foo'
        });
        $("#example3").myPlugin({
            exampleData: 'too'
        });

        $('.click').click(function () {
            console.log($("#example1").myPlugin('getData'));
            console.log($("#example2").myPlugin('getData'));
            console.log($("#example3").myPlugin('getData'));
        });
    });
```

I want the result on the console to be:

```
'bar'
'foo'
'too'
```

I tried to accomplish this with the following code:

```
(function ($) {
$.myPlugin = function (options) {
    $.myPlugin.settings = $.extend({
        exampleData: 'default value'
    }, options);
}

$.fn.myPlugin = function (methodOrOptions) {
    var methods = {
        getData: function () {
            return $(this).settings.exampleData;
        },
        init: function (options) {
            new $.myPlugin(options);
        }
    }

    if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
        return methods[methodOrOptions].apply($(this), Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
        return methods.init.apply($(this), arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin');
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

But I get "Unable to get property 'exampleData' of undefined or null reference"

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is with this line:

```
return $(this).settings.exampleData;
```

`$(this)` returns a jQuery set, and jQuery sets don't have a `settings` property.

One main thing to remember when writing a plugin is that you get called with a jQuery set, but everything you do has to work on just subsets of that set. Example:

```
// Initialize on a set that includes *all* paragraphs
$("p").myPlugin();

// ...

// But now we do something with just the third paragraph; the
// plugin should expect that and store information on a per-
// element basis, not a per-set basis
$("p").eq(2).myPlugin("doSomething");
```

One fairly simple way to do that is to store information using jQuery's `data` function.

For what it's worth, here's an example of a basic plugin that has "setData" and "getData" methods. Details in comments in the code:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    // Defaults
    var defaults = {
        // ...
    };

    // Methods
    var methods = {
        // (Note that `initialize` isn't on this list)
        getData:    getData,
        setData:    setData
    };

    // Utils
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    // Expose the plugin
    $.fn.myPlugin = myPlugin;

    // Main entry point to plugin
    function myPlugin(arg) {
        var args = slice.call(arguments, 0);
        var method;
        var rv;

        // What are we doing?
        switch (typeof arg) {
            case "undefined":
            case "object":
                // Initializing
                rv = initialize.call(this, args);
                break;

            case "string":
                // Method, do we know it?
                method = methods[arg];
                if (!method) {
                    throw new Error("myPlugin: Unknown method '" + arg + "'");
                }
                args.shift(); // We've consumed the method name

                // Do it, return whatever it returns
                rv = method.call(this, args);
                break;

            default:
                throw new Error("myPlugin: Expected string or object as first argument if argument given.");
        }

        return rv;
    }

    // Initialize the plugin
    function initialize(args) {
        // Get the options
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, args[0]);

        // Loop through, initializing the elements
        this.each(function() {
            // ...
            // (if appropriate here, you might detect whether you're being re-initialized
            // for the same element)
        });

        // Enable chaining
        return this;
    }

    // Get data
    function getData(args) {
        // "Get" operations only apply to the first element
        // Return the data; normally `args` wouldn't be used
        return this.first().data("myPlugin");
    }

    // Set data; "set" operations apply to all elements
    function setData(args) {
        this.data("myPlugin", args[0]);
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/yikiq/1)

Comment: That's what I call an exhaustive answer - thank you very much, it helped me a lot. By the way, I haven't mentioned it in the question but is there a way to restrict the usage of the plugin to unique elements only? Meaning, a restriction that would allow the plugin to work only if the jQuery selector is something like $('#uniqueElement'), but not $('p') or $('.someElementClass #anotherElementUniqueId .theElement')? How can I check this and throw an error if such situation is present?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder:  background:  I'm not a front-end guy... Two quick questions:  where does `arguments` come from in the line `var args = slice.call(arguments, 0);` and how are the options accessed? I don't understand how you get from `var options = ...` to having those available in the plugin, if that var isn't anywhere else, and isn't returned? -- Third question (sorry) can you point me in a direction to understand the `($this).each()` in the `initialize` function? I know what `($this).each()` does - I just don't understand what it would be working on in this context

Comment: @PhillipHarrington: All non-arrow functions have an automatic `arguments` object containing the arguments they were called with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope%2Farguments

Comment: @PhillipHarrington: (Re your edit) You'd use `options` in the code within the `each` callback. Re `each`: Plugins are called with `this` referring to the jQuery object they were called on. So `this.each` is using http://api.jquery.com/each/ to operate on each element in the jQuery object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Why wouldn't I just say `this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, args[0])` ? Would the `each()` funciton have to do a swtich to see what the arg was?

Comment: @PhillipHarrington: You don't want to assign properties to a jQuery object. And no, I don't see any need for a switch.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - is `this` in the `initialize` function the jQuery object for the selected element? The `$("p")` or `$("p").eq(2)`  ?

Comment: @PhillipHarrington: Due respect, comments aren't the place to do a tutorial on jQuery plugins. As I said above, `this` will refer to the jQuery object (not a DOM element, a wrapper). It's not the same as you're used to in event handlers. For further clarifications, post a question (after doing research, tutorials, etc.). Good luck!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was merely trying to understand and learn from your example. I didn't mean to offend or pry a tutorial out of you; that was all I had to ask. Thanks for answering. I'll let you get back to your work